# Destructive interference of Gravitational Waves and the Conservation of Energy

Tags: energy-conservation, interference, gravitational-waves, superposition

Destructive interferences are interesting for a physics student, specifically when checking the Energy Conservation. In the case of destructive EM waves or String waves it is easy to understand where the energy goes. However, it is not clear to me where it goes in the case of two Gravitational Waves’ destructive interference. Can anyone answer this question?

Comment: Why would the same reason as the case of EM or string waves, or any other waves (sound waves in any medium, surface water waves, ...), not work for gravitational waves ? What arguments do you have to think is would be different ? The answer is simply : destructive interferences in some places are exactly compensated by constructive interferences in other places.